# pgbouncer + SQLAlchemy on "high?" load produces "high level exception...(psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out"

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

I have a datawarehouse type environment with dozens of workers sending queries through a pgbouncer proxy. Its been running for a couple years now with mostly no issues. Just recently we started getting this error:

```
high level exception for item: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "something.com" (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 6432?
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

And though I don't know exactly what things have looked like before the error, looking at `SHOW POOL;`s I can see that the main database that everything is connecting to routinely has several seconds of delay and in general seems very busy. `cl_active` is approximate 80-200 - not sure how that measures up but I don't think its terribly high.

Some relevant settings (everything else is default):

```
pool_mode = transaction
max_client_conn=1000
max_db_connections=250
server_idle_timeout = 60.0
```

The errors are kind of sporadic and I haven't been able to find a pattern yet. But the thing that is really making me scratch my head is that the actual volume isn't actually that high. The receiving database isn't overwhelmed and even if it were, that would be pgbouncer's job to manage delays. So the delays are not my concern but the connection errors.

I am unsure how to diagnose this more or what settings might be useful. Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

One question I have is if there is a way to log how many connection attempts there are over a period?

Comment: Which field is showing the "several seconds of delay"?  And what are all the other values shown by SHOW POOLS, as well?

Comment: @jjanes `cl_active` was in the 80-200 range; `sv_active` was usually up to 10, which was the max; and `maxwait` was ±3 on average. All the other fields were 0.

Comment: Update: after doing lots of tests, the evidence seemed very clear that the pgbouncer service was not the bottleneck but rather the network interface and how many connections it could handle. Still, I had a very hard time getting clear metrics/answers to this or figuring out how to increase my AWS resources so that they could handle more incoming connection requests. But I can pretty confidently conclude that it wasn't pgbouncer doing the limiting.